# Python - Write a code that takes values from one list, based on the values from another list and print the text of the output**

Tags: python

**5 - Write a code that takes values from one list, based on the values from another list and print the text of the output**

#base list:
list1 = [1, 7, 5, 2, 10, 34, 621, 45, 7, 76, 23, "a", 14, 6]

#to exclude from base list
list2 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 7, 10, 23, 14]

**Right Answer:** List1 lost 6 elements and now has 8 elements

My code :

```
lost=0
for i in list1:
    if i in list2:
        list1.remove(i)
       lost+=1
print("List1 lost  {} elements and now has  {} elements".format(lost,len(list1)))
```

I've been printed the List 1 after ran the code and that was the answer:

list1 = [1, 5, 2, 34, 621, 45, 76, 'a', 6]

Why the 'a' are nothing being excluded from list1 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension to iterate over `list1` and keep elements that are not also in `list2`, for performance reasons you can reduce `list2` to a set to keep only unique elements and make the membership check faster.

```
>>> list1 = [i for i in list1 if i not in set(list2)]
>>> list1
[1, 5, 2, 34, 621, 45, 76, 6]
```

Your current implementation will not work because you should not `remove` items from a list as you are iterating through it, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/how-to-remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating) for further details about that.